# Recovering a function from the Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I have the following relation

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a(x,u)\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi u}}\,\exp\left(-\frac{h^2}{2u}\right)\,du.$$

How do I find the expression for $a(x,u)$ from this?

My attempt: The integral on LHS looks like the Laplace transform in $\dfrac{h^2}{2}$ if $u$ is replaced by $\dfrac{1}{u}$. I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: For $u>0$ $a(x,u)$ should behave at list as $\sim\frac{1}{u^\alpha}, \alpha>\frac{1}{2}$ to ensure the integral convergence - because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi u}}exp(-\frac{h^2}{2u})\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi u}}$ for $u\to\infty$.  For $u<0$ $\sqrt u$ and integral itself are not well defined.

Comment: Don’t you have to know $f(x)$ in order to obtain $a(x,u)$?  Both are functions, correct?

Comment: @Svyatoslav Sorry I forgot to mention this but $f(x)$ is a complex function.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Yes you can assume $f(x)$ to be given.

Comment: @Svyatoslav In order to be the “traditional Gaussian”, $u$ must be $u^2$.